# Get Object from Model Browser after click Visible/Invisible icon Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

How do I get the objects I've filtered from the model browse? I've used OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, but it's only used the first time when the model is loaded.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6DQz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to `HIDE_EVENT` and `SHOW_EVENT`. You will get the dbid of hidden or showed nodes.

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.HIDE_EVENT, (nodes, model)=> {   
     
     // nodes returns an object like that :
     // {type: "hide", nodeIdArray: [<dbid>], model: Model, target: GuiViewer3D}

})

viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_EVENT, (nodes, model)=> {   
     
     // nodes returns an object like that :
     // {type: "show", nodeIdArray:[<dbid>], model: Model, target: GuiViewer3D}

})
```

Also, if you want to access the complete list of hidden nodes for a model, you can use `viewer.getHiddenNodes(model)`

Comment: VisibilityManager.js:459 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getHiddenNodes')
    at s.getHiddenNodes (VisibilityManager.js:459:40)
    at C.he.getHiddenNodes (Viewer3D.js:2488:44)
    at forge.viewer.js:84:12

Comment: You probably have a problem with your model reference. Can you try this command `NOP_VIEWER.getHiddenNodes(NOP_VIEWER.model)` ?

Comment: hi alex i got the same error message. Do you have a reference code?
this is my reference code
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-model.derivative-nodejs-xls.exporter


thanks Alex

Comment: Try this code I use both functions I described in my answer : [Learn Forge Viewhubmodels NodeJS](https://github.com/AlexPiro/learn.forge.viewhubmodels/tree/nodejs)